# jQuery determinate dropped item (drop event)

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-events

I would like to change background colors of a class after drop differents elements

- If drop card1 -> class .stack should be blue
- If drop card2 -> class .stack should be red

```
$(".stackDrop").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".card1, .card2",
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {        
        $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
        $('.stack').css('background-color','red');
    }
});
```

There is a link to jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/70x2set8/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to dropped card properties from event with `$(event.ElementTo)` so one solution could be:

```
 $(".stackDrop").droppable({
            tolerance: "intersect",
            accept: ".card1, .card2",
            activeClass: "ui-state-default",
            hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
            drop: function(event, ui) {        
                $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
                if($(event.toElement).hasClass("card1"))
                    $('.stack').css('background-color','blue');
                if($(event.toElement).hasClass("card2"))
                    $('.stack').css('background-color','red');
            }
        });
```

but I suggest a better way with a key-value objects array:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var array = [{key:"card1", value:"blue"},{key:"card2", value:"red"}]
  $(".card1, .card2").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    cursor: "move",
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: "invalid",
  });

  $(".stackDrop").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".card1, .card2",
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
      array.forEach(function(el){
        if($(event.toElement).hasClass(el.key))
            $('.stack').css('background-color',el.value);
      })

    }
  });
});
```

As you can see, with this solution, you can add more items and set their class and color into the array.

Comment: You are wizard!! Thank you so much!